# sql joining three tables using inner joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join

in my database I have 3 tables named `items`, `manufacturers` and `items_manufacturers`. `manufacturers` has a HAS:MANY relation with `items_manufacturers`

My `items` table

```
 +---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| code          | varchar(25)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| item_category | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| item_desc     | varchar(500) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| reorder_point | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| unit          | varchar(45)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

My `manufacturers` table

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| code       | varchar(25)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| name       | varchar(250) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| address    | varchar(750) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| contact_no | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

My `items_manufacturers` table

```
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | bigint(20)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| item_id         | bigint(20)    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| manufacturer_id | bigint(20)    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| unit_cost       | decimal(20,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| vendor_id       | bigint(20)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

In my result table I want `items_id`, `items_desc`, `name` of manufacturer from `manufacturers` table and `manufacturer_id`. The relation I have is

```
items.id=items_manufacturers.item_id and
manufacturers.id=items_manufacturers.manufacturer_id.
```

I tried using inner joins for three tables but not working.
The query  I tried

```
select 
  items_manufacturers.id,
  items.item_desc,
  item_manufacturers.manufacturer_id,
  manufacturer.name 
from items_manufacturers 
INNER JOIN items ON items_manufacturers.item_id=items.id 
INNER JOIN manufacturers ON items_manufacturers.manufacturer_id=manufacturers.id
```

Anybody kindly help me with this, I am stuck up from a long time

Comment: The query looks OK. When you say it's not working, what do you mean? Can you explain why the results don't match what you are expecting?

Comment: As Jim asked above, I would like to know why is not working? Do you get any error? Do you get any incosistent results? As far as I can see, your query seems to me ok.

Comment: this gets me curious since you seem to have a working query, but you say that you are stuck long time..

Comment: ya iam not getting the desired results . i want all records where items_manufacturers.manufacturer_id=manufacturer.id but i am getting only for id=27 which is not the desired result

Comment: Could you set this up with http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Could you please correct your (minor) syntax errors in your stated query?  Yes, we need sample data for this... Although perhaps it's a transaction-related issue?  Often, for cross-reference tables, they tend to just the composite key from the referenced tables, and not have their own (as such an id is rarely referred to).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used this following code and got the result you were trying to get. This code may solve your  problem:

```
select a.name,b.manufacturer_id,c.id,c.item_desc 
from manufacturers as a
inner join 
item_manufacturers as b
on b.manufacturer_id=a.id 
inner join item as c 
on c.id=b.item_id
```

Comment: Could you state for the gallery why you think reordering parts of the statement (that _shouldn't_ make a difference) and using aliasing will solve the problem?

Comment: no no I solved it, finally without using joins just I selected the columns and gave the where clause.